How to completly contain SPA in component? / Simulate smaller Viewport
I want to display already existing SPA's in components for showcasing purposes. The aim is to basically have 6 or so "windows" on a single page each containing a page. The problem is that things like toasts, modals, popups, background blurs/opacity wont stay inside the container no matter what I try. I've tried IFrame and single-spa so far, I've managed that the pages are mostly contained but some elements are still displayed outside of its supposed boundaries. For example one page has an input form that opens in screen center and blurs the background.
The child pages have a dozen components each with fixed/absolute styling, viewport percentages and different z-indizes, changing them all is out of the question.
How do I basically "simulate" to the childs that the parent container is the entire display size?
